# Reading in JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

Keep having issue reading in JSON file.  I've tried everything from changing cwd to specifying absolute path... but nothing seems to work.  Here is the current code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/NEHRU/Desktop/New Project')
cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))


with open('C:\\Users\\NEHRU\\Desktop\\New Project\\identities.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

And this is the output I keep getting:

```
PS C:\Users\NEHRU> & C:/Users/NEHRU/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/NEHRU/Desktop/New Project/import json.py"
Files in 'C:\\Users\\NEHRU\\Desktop\\New Project': ['collection.json', 'identities.json', 'import json.py', 'Project Instructions']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\NEHRU\Desktop\New Project\import json.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load     
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads    
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode    
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 27 column 3 (char 238)
PS C:\Users\NEHRU>
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the file (formatting) itself. What are the contents of line 27?

Comment: share sample of json file if you can. Or validate your json

Comment: You're not getting a file-not-found error. The problem is with the contents of the file being read.

Comment: Be careful with spaces on directories and filenames. On windows, it gets tricky to use them inside a script. I normally prefer to not use them at all. In the windows console, for example, directories with special characters or spaces are written between qutoes `"C:\\like this"`. You can test that with the `cd` command.

Comment: Also, from this line `File "c:\Users\NEHRU\Desktop\New Project\import json.py", line 12, in <module>`, your python script contains space as filename. This is also not advised. Just ask yourself, how would you import this module later on?